# OO Design, pass parameters between private methods or access member variable?

Tags: c#, oop

Say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int memberVar;

    public MyClass(int passedInVar)
    {
        memberVar = passedInVar;       
    }
}
```

In the constructor you pass in an int and assign it to a private member variable.

My question is, is it better to pass that int variable around between private methods of the class, or to not pass the int variable as a parameter and instead have each private method directly access the private membervar?

i.e. Is this (Example A):

```
class MyClass
{
    private int memberVar;

    public MyClass(int passedInVar)
    {
        memberVar = passedInVar;       
    }

    public MyPublicMethod()
    {
        MyPrivateMethod(memberVar);
    }

    public MyPrivateMethod(int variable)
    {
        // Do something with passed in variable...
    }
}
```

better than this (Example B):

```
class MyClass
{
    private int memberVar;

    public MyClass(int passedInVar)
    {
        memberVar = passedInVar;       
    }

    public MyPublicMethod()
    {
        MyPrivateMethod();
    }

    public MyPrivateMethod()
    {
        // Do something with memberVar...
    }
}
```

The reason I ask is that I find myself switching between the two styles.

I find that example the style of example A shows more intent for the code. You can see what is being passed between private methods so it's more obvious what is being affected by that method.

Whereas Example B is cleaner because the memberVar isn't being passed between private methods. However the code feels more "side-effecty" because it's not always obvious which private member variables the method is acting on.

I'd appreciate your opinions on which approach you consider best.

Comment: Why would you've this private variable if you don't use it globally in your class?

Comment: @Richard Moore I would choose the second approach as the declaration of `memberVar` is accessible to all methods so passing the variable would be pointless.

Comment: I would say that it depends on the scenario, perhaps the private method can perform an action on a value supplied, this would make the method more flexible as you wouldn't have to set a field every time you wanted to use the method. I'd say as long as you keep it consistent throughout your application with code standards I don't think either method would be any better than the other, except as said in certain scenarios.

Comment: The way you structure your private attributes and methods is completely up to you, since they are encapsulated within the class. Having said that, option B seems the most sensible to me, given that you're all the time within the same scope.

Comment: In most of the time, I prefer the first approach. I feel that it is a proper function (in and out), and does not have a dependency on the private variable. Functions in mathematics have input and output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of telling you which is better, I prefer to give you some hints:

- Class fields should never be accessed directly. They should be encapsulated using *properties*.
- Instance methods, since they're part of some specific class instance shouldn't accept parameters unless the values required during the execution of some method requires more information than the one contained in the object itself or if the data shouldn't be held by the class because they not represent actual properties on the whole class (i.e. the data is unrelated to the class).
- You shouldn't create a private method just to operate with class fields, because you should already encapsulate them using properties.
- Class fields that are only set during construction time should be `readonly` to avoid human mistakes setting it during the life-time of the whole object. At least, you should set a property where its *setter* is private (i.e. `public string Name { get; private set; }`).

## Expanding *when to use input parameters*

For example, calculating the area of a rectangle would look as follows:

```
public class Rectangle
{
     public int Area { get; private set; }

     public void CalcArea(int a, int b) 
     {
          Area = a * b;
     }
}
```

- `Area` is a class property. You wouldn't pass the area as argument of `CalcArea`, would you? ;)
- You need to supply the length of rectangle's sides.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but what's the difference between a `class field` and a `class property`?

Comment: @gen A class field is the storage, and properties are the accessors to fields (and some other things like calculated properties...). Properties encapsulate access to fields so one may define that some data is read-only, write-only, read-write, and even all combinations with visibility modifiers (private, protected, internal, public)

Answer (score 5):

Voted for the second solve. You are working with current context and it is a normal - use context parts. It's right for life, it's right for code. 
For example imaging that you use strategy 1. If one of your private methods, which called 2 or more once, needs change signature, then you need change code at 2 or more places. Otherwise, when you use context, it`s not needed.

Answer (score 4):

The real question is not "which way is better", it is whether your member variable should really be a member of your class or not. If it is only a member variable to clean up the argument list for some operation... that is not a good reason to add members to a class. Not only does it polute your model and makes your code harder to understand, it scatters dependencies which is never a good thing. If you can make your method static by passing in its dependencies it is probably good to do so.

If the member is a rightful member of your class, you probably do not need a separate method at all. Then passing the member from one method to the next makes no sense because the member can always be accessed by any method,

Answer (score 2):

I would chose the first approach in this concrete scenario, as the function declaration clearly manifests what its execution depends from.

In second case you have "hidden" variable that holds the state during entire lifetime of the type instance.

There are number *pros* and *cons*, and that pretty much depends on all program architecture, your design goals and personal test.

Considering all I said above, still, having clear and concise definition of the function which *at the same time* clearly shows its execution dependencies  (like in your first choice) is a huge benefit I find hard to argue about.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer misses out on a few aspects. Here are my two cents.

> Class fields should never be accessed directly.

Class fields should **always** be accessed directly, unless the behavior of the property setter is desired! Under the hood, properties are methods. Accessing a property is like calling a method. It might be harder for the optimizer to get rid of the extra method call. Not to mention the common case where the property setter will trigger a costly event (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`). You also have the case where the property is `virtual`, implying additional side effects.

> Instance methods /.../ shouldn't accept parameters

Mostly correct. Though, if you have a private *instance* method you are a few steps away from making it `static` - saving some CPU cycles for the actual method call (no `vtable` lookup).

> You shouldn't create a private method just to operate with class
>   fields

You **should** create private methods when several methods need to do the exact same work as part of their responsibility. E.g.:

```
private void OnSizeChanged()
{
    this.area = CalcArea();   // Here...
    this.perimeter = CalcPerimeter();
}

public float GetPhysicalArea(float unit)
{
    return CalcArea() * unit; // ... and here!
}
```